# php combine multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble combining these two arrays so that the keys are kept together.  The problem (I think) I'm having is that the arrays don't match in their structures, and the array keys are integers in one and names in the other.  I feel like I need to have one array (feel free to correct me) so that I can display the prices coherently on the page, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it.  I tried an array_merge, but it looses the indexed tlds sub-array:

```
$result = array();
foreach($cats[0]['domorder'] as $domorder) {
    $result = array_merge($domorder, $prices[0]);
}
```

Maybe I can somehow (this isn't working either) add a 'price' sub-array that won't be overwritten?

```
$result = array();
$prc = array();
$prc['price'] = $prices[0];
foreach($prc as $p) {
$result = array_merge($p, $cats[0]['domorder'][0]);
}
```

Here's basically what I'm working with...my apologies if these are not formatted correctly for questions here.

**Array 1, category definitions of hosting/domain name products:**

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hosting] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vpslinuxin
                    [1] => resellerhostinglinuxuk
                    [2] => resellerwindowshostinguk
                    ........etc,etc.........
                    [34] => hosting
                )

            [domorder] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [dombiz] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => biz
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [dominfo] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => info
                                )

                        )
                    ........etc,etc.........
```

---

Array 2, prices associated to the above categorized products:

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [resellerhostinglinuxuk] => Array
                (
                    [131] => Array
                        (
                            [renew] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 43.19
                                )

                            [ssl] => 4.79
                            [add] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 43.19
                                )

                        )
                        ........etc,etc.........
            [dombiz] => Array
                (
                    [addtransferdomain] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 10.69
                        )

                    [restoredomain] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 69.95
                        )

                    [addnewdomain] => Array
                        (
                            [10] => 10.89
                            [9] => 10.89
                )
                        ........etc,etc.........
```

Anyone?  I feel like this should be a fairly easy merge, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

**Edit**

Here's an example of how I think it should work:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hosting] => Array
                (
                    [vpslinuxin] => Array
                    (
                    [prices] => Array
                            (
                        [addons] => Array
                            (
                            .......
                            )
                        [plans] => Array
                            (
                            .......
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            [domorder] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                        [dombiz] => Array
                            (
                                [tlds] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => biz
                                    )
                                [prices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [addtransferdomain] => Array
                                            (
                                                .......
                                            )
                                        [restoredomain] => Array
                                            (
                                                .......
                                            )
                                        [addnewdomain] => Array
                                            (
                                                .......
                                            )
                                        [renewdomain] => Array
                                            (
                                            .......
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: What would the output array look like?

Comment: That question is part of the problem.  I'm trying to figure out how it would even work, considering the difference between indexed and associative arrays.

Comment: What I mean is can you post an example of how you might like it to look? For example, would you like the subarrays under `resellerhostinglinuxuk` to be combined under the `resellerhostinglinuxuk` key of the `hosting` array?

Comment: Ok, I've added an example of how it might work.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help Michael but I managed to get it.

I was thinking too hard about it, so after dinner and some relaxing, I decided to simplify what I've been trying.  There's no hard/fast rule saying that the two arrays need to be together - ultimately they're going to end up together anyway.  So I just appended one to the other, defined by a 'product' and 'price' key:

```
$result = array();
$result[]['product'] = $cats[0];
$result[]['prices'] = $prices[0];
```